# Running Xcode Project on iPhone - Black Screen?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

When I run my project on the iOS Simulator or on my iPhone, half of one particular view controller becomes a black screen. None of the functionality for that view controller is there, and half of the screen is black. However, the "Back" button at the top of the View Controller is still there, and it works. This View Controller should have a Table View and a UILabel. However, neither of those appear. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the content settings for the simulator

Comment: How do I do this?